Unable to load converted image into ImageSource stream
I am developing a simple MAUI application that stores a table into an SQLite database. The code works for store and recall. The table, once read back is converted into another model and a filename is then converted into an ImageSource using the following method
public static async Task<ImageSource> ToImageSource(this string filename)
{
    try
    {
        var data = "";

        using var fileStream = await FileSystem.Current.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(filename);
        using var reader = new StreamReader(fileStream);
        data = reader.ReadToEnd();
        byte[] image = Convert.FromBase64String(data);
        MemoryStream ms = new (image);
        return ImageSource.FromStream(() => ms);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        throw;
    }
}

If I pass in a filename (say mpte.png), the app tells me this file can't be found. I'm guessing it's because .NET MAUI converts svg files into png files and then stores them somewhere in the app structure.
My issue is that I don't know where these converted files will be stored and there isn't anything (that I can see) in the documentation to say where to look.

Why are you using FromBase64String?  You are making this way too complicated.  Just use ImageSource.FromFile as shown in the docs

As a test, I used an image which format is Base64String to test, the result is that I could display the image normally.

If I pass in a filename (say mpte.png), the app tells me this file can't be found How can we reproduce this problem? Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem?
